# Connect windows 2000 to sql server 2016

Tags: sql-server-2016, ssl

I have a really old piece of industrial equipment that connects from windows professional to a sql server 2008r2 on win 2008R2, not completely patched.
We cannot replace the windows 2000, but would like to connect to a sql server 2016.

This is the connection string in the udl file
[oledb]
; Everything after this line is an OLE DB initstring
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=blabla;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=LVD;Initial Catalog=LVDLASER;Data Source=someserver

It works if I point to the old server.
If I change the servername, test it on a win 10 machine, it works.
On the win2000 I get this:
[image]

Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider.
[DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (SECDoClientHandshake()).SSL Security error.

Any suggestion is very much appreciated.

Comment: I cannot tell you exactly how to rectify this, but an idea you may follow: Probably the protocol version or ciphers the 2016 offers are too new and not supported by the 2000.

Comment: Which client do you have installed on the Windows 2000 machine? I think the latest version that works on Windows 2000 is the SQL Server Native Client(SQL Server 2005). Whether or not it can connect to SQL Server 2016 I don't know. Also suggest trying to connect without SSL, if possible. I know it's not secure but I guess in your case functionality trumps security.

Comment: I wonder if there is some way of proxying a connection via another PC. But my first line of thinking would be to get rid of Windows 2000, it must have a huge amount of security holes by now. I'd be interested to know why it cannot be replaced with Windows 10 or Server 2016+

Comment: To add to sticky bit's comment, the newest version of SSL/TLS that works on Windows 2000 is TLS 1.0. SQL 2016 on a modern OS _can_ talk TLS 1.0. But it is possible that TLS 1.0 and 1.1 were disabled on your SQL 2016 server for security/compliance purposes. If so, the two machines can't agree on a TLS version, and that would give an error like you are seeing.

Comment: The 2000 cannot be replaced because it is part of a laser cutting machine that has a built in computer. That computer runs windows 2000, is +15 yrs old.

Comment: The installed client is the mdac_typ.exe v2.8
I disabled tls 1.1 and tls 1.2 on the 2016 server with this tool https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/
with the same result.
I made some traces with wireshark, but the tls negotiation is not visible. Also not for a working connection from a modern client.
There is not much info available on how the tds protocol handles tls. 
It looks like a certificate is not required for tls on the sql server which looks strange to me.
openssl test to the server gives results without a certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Colin's suggestion fixed it. Installed windows installer 3.1 and found the native client 2005 somewhere and now it is ok.
Works also for sql server 2019 on windows 2019.